# Strange dark stripes on procedural texture

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, materials, texture-baking

I made a wall with a procedural texture on it.
I wanted to bake that texture to an image but **Cycles** creates some dark stripes on one part of the model which are transfered to the baked texture as well.

I don't know how to get rid of that or what causes this effect anyway.I'm using Blender 2.83.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Fair enough.I edited the image.Unfortunately they are not shadows.I upload the blend file as soon as I find out how to do that on this site.(Should I upload it somwhere and share the link?)Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Done.I hope it's working...

Comment: OK, I did it for you :) Since this site is meant to be knowledge-base (so others can learn from you) and external links like google drive is not permanent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*You could probably discover it by your self ... just by detaching nodes from tree.*

I ended up with this **Noise Texture node with Scale 100** ...

[image]

... behaviour is weird, but probably values are to extreme, changing **Detail** from 16 to **15 seems to work**.

[image]

My guess ... you don't need for such Scale to use such Details even Detail 4 would do the job.

Anyway this is not happening with Blender 3.x

Comment: Thank for the soulution. I'm not new to blender but i'm new to this procedural texture thing in it.I've got that setting from a tutorial on youtube from a sophisticated guy who knows what he is doing.In fact that was the only part in the shader I didn't change.But at least you taught me how to debug these things.Thank you.Have a nice day.